# How I can transform SELECT query to DELETE for remove extra taxonomy unwanted?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, phpmyadmin

I try this query shows me the products that have duplicated, term_taxonomy_id in my web corresponds the stock of the product
(none, medium, high, low) **image Bottom***

I would like to transform it into one query DELETE... that will delete those that have repeated and leave only the most current by the term_order, because if the product have two stock tag or more is not displayed on the web.

**They only have to have a tag**,
*object_id=1 have high,none* |
*object_id=3 have none, medium*
**this is my problem.**

```
table: wp_term_relationships
+-----------+------------------+-----------+
| object_id | term_taxonomy_id | term_order|
+-----------+------------------+-----------+
| 1         | high             | 0         |
| 1         | none             | 1         |<---delete none
| 1         | bbb              | 10        |
| 1         | ccc              | 10        |
| 2         | high             | 0         |
| 2         | aaa              | 11        |
| 2         | bbb              | 11        |
| 2         | ccc              | 11        |
| 3         | none             | 0         |
| 3         | medium           | 1         |<---delete medium
| 3         | high             | 12        |<---delete high
| 4         | jjj              | 12        |
| 5         | kkk              | 12        |
| 5         | lll              | 12        |
| 5         | high             | 12        |
| *         | *                | *         |
+-----------+------------------+-----------+
```

[image of the table because in the mobile version is not right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eQ5v.png)

```
SELECT object_id,term_taxonomy_id,term_order 
FROM wp_term_relationships 
WHERE (    term_taxonomy_id = none
        OR term_taxonomy_id = medium
        OR term_taxonomy_id = high
        OR term_taxonomy_id = low)
GROUP BY object_id
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

***Image with the problem:** https://ibb.co/k5XLCdS

Answer (score 1):

This is the query that you need ,  do a test

```
delete  wp_term_relationships  
from  wp_term_relationships 
 inner join ( 
SELECT object_id,term_taxonomy_id,term_order 
FROM  wp_term_relationships a
WHERE (    term_taxonomy_id = 'none'
        OR term_taxonomy_id = 'medium'
        OR term_taxonomy_id = 'high'
        OR term_taxonomy_id = 'low') and (
select sum(if(v.term_taxonomy_id in  ('high','none','medium','low') , 1, 0)) from wp_term_relationships as v where v.object_id = a.object_id) > 1  
except
SELECT object_id,term_taxonomy_id,term_order
FROM  wp_term_relationships 
WHERE (    term_taxonomy_id = 'none'
        OR term_taxonomy_id = 'medium'
        OR term_taxonomy_id = 'high'
        OR term_taxonomy_id = 'low')
GROUP BY object_id
HAVING COUNT(*)>1 ) y on 
wp_term_relationships.object_id = y.object_id and 
wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = y.term_taxonomy_id and
wp_term_relationships.term_order = y.term_order
```

[db<>fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=d88784eaa40405268ce8d2d793a8c0dd)

Comment: Thank you Omari, but my server not support EXCEPT, MySQL said: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'except' , I try change for NOT IN, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: @beikone tested on MariaDB. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=d88784eaa40405268ce8d2d793a8c0dd and expect works okay try mayb you didn't remove properly the `test_db.` retry now.